NLOpt vector-valued inequality constraint function signature in C++
I'm working on implementing a nonlinear optimization problem using the NLOpt library, and I'm having some trouble defining a vector-valued inequality constraint using the C++ interface.
The NLOpt docs seem to indicate that they support defining cost functions and both equality and inequality constraint functions that accept std::vector<double>& arguments, as opposed to pointers to arrays (double*). See the myvfunc() and myvconstraint() signatures in the "Example in C++" section of the following link.
So far, I've had success writing both my cost function and my equality constraint with the following function signatures:
double cost_fcn(const std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& grad, void* data);
double eq_constraint(const std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& grad, void* data);

The NLOpt docs also describe support for vector-valued equality and inequality constraints. But the function signatures (shown below) that they provide are in the C format (using array pointers).
void ineq_constraint(
   unsigned m, double *result, unsigned n, const double* x, double* grad, void* f_data);

where m is the dimension of the constraint vector and n is the dimension of the parameter space.
It's not clear from the docs that the C++-style function signature is supported for vector-valued constraints, but I've tried to implement the following and it's not working:
void ineq_constraint(
   std::vector<double>& result, const std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& grad, void* data);

At this point, I'll switch to trying to use the C-style function signature, but it would be nice to get a definitive answer as to whether or not NLOpt currently supports the C++ style function signature for vector-valued constraints.

After taking a closer look at the NLOpt C header (nlopt.h), there are 2 valid function signature types that NLOpt defines: nlopt_func and nlopt_mfunc.
typedef double (*nlopt_func) (unsigned n,
                              const double *x,
                              double *gradient, /* NULL if not needed */
                              void *func_data);

typedef void (*nlopt_mfunc) (unsigned m,
                             double *result,
                             unsigned n,
                             const double *x,
                             double *gradient, /* NULL if not needed */
                             void *func_data);

The NLOpt C++ header (nlopt.hpp) adds a third valid function signature type (vfunc) and provides aliases (func and mfunc) for the above two types.
typedef nlopt_func func;   // nlopt::func synoynm
typedef nlopt_mfunc mfunc; // nlopt::mfunc synoynm

typedef double (*vfunc)(const std::vector<double> &x,
                        std::vector<double> &grad,
                        void *data);

opt::set_min_objective and the scalar-valued constraint functions ( opt::add_equality_constraint and opt::add_inequality_constraint) are overloaded for both the func and vfunc types, i.e. both C and C++-style objective and scalar-valued constraint functions are supported.
But when it comes to vector-valued constraint functions, the vfunc (C++-style) function type is not supported. Only the mfunc type is currently supported (nlopt.hpp:434).
It might make a nice addition to NLOpt to add support for the C++-style function signature (vfunc) for vector-valued constraint functions.

No, the NLOpt C++ wrapper still uses the C declaration of the vector valued constraints github function link, in C++ a zero cost abstraction would be wrapping those arguments in a std::span, but that's C++20, or available in boost::span for C++17 (you can copy 2 headers from boost to get the span in your code-base) or you can use GSL span (you need to copy more headers here), you can write a zero cost wrapper to convert between the C API and the C++ API.
the funtions that accept std::vector& are wasteful as they have to copy the values into the vectors then copy the result out of the vectors, which is slower than the (almost) zero cost span.
this is a modified example of NLOpt Docs that uses vector-valued constraints and wraps it in a proper C++ interface with spans.
#include <nlopt.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <span>

struct my_constraint_data  {
    double a, b;
};

double myvfunc(const std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& grad, void* my_func_data)
{
    if (!grad.empty()) {
        grad[0] = 0.0;
        grad[1] = 0.5 / sqrt(x[1]);
    }
    return sqrt(x[1]);
}

double myvconstraint(std::span<const double> x, std::span<double> grad, my_constraint_data& data)
{
    my_constraint_data* d = &data;
    double a = d->a, b = d->b;
    if (!grad.empty()) {
        grad[0] = 3 * a * (a * x[0] + b) * (a * x[0] + b);
        grad[1] = -1.0;
    }
    return ((a * x[0] + b) * (a * x[0] + b) * (a * x[0] + b) - x[1]);
}


void my_mfunc(std::span<double> result, std::span<const double> x, std::span<double> grad, void* f_data)
{
    auto data_ptr = static_cast<my_constraint_data*>(f_data);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
    {
        result[i] = myvconstraint(x, grad.size() ? grad.subspan(i * x.size(), x.size()) : std::span<double>{}, data_ptr[i]);
    }
}

using mfunc_type = void (*)(std::span<double>, std::span<const double>, std::span<double>, void*);

template <mfunc_type func>
void m_to_span_transform(unsigned m, double* result, unsigned n, const double* x, double* grad, void* f_data)
{
    func(std::span<double>{result, result + m}, std::span<const double>{x, x + n}, grad ? std::span<double>{grad, grad + m*n} : std::span<double>{}, f_data);
}


int main()
{
    nlopt::opt opt(nlopt::LD_SLSQP, 2);
    std::vector<double> lb(2);
    lb[0] = -HUGE_VAL; lb[1] = 0;
    opt.set_lower_bounds(lb);
    opt.set_min_objective(myvfunc, NULL);
    my_constraint_data data[2] = { {2,0}, {-1,1} };
    opt.add_inequality_mconstraint(m_to_span_transform<my_mfunc>, (void*)&data, { 1e-8, 1e-8 });
    opt.set_xtol_rel(1e-4);
    std::vector<double> x(2);
    x[0] = 1.234; x[1] = 5.678;
    double minf;

    try {
        nlopt::result result = opt.optimize(x, minf);
        std::cout << "found minimum at f(" << x[0] << "," << x[1] << ") = "
            << std::setprecision(10) << minf << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "nlopt failed: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

for C++17 just replace every use of std::span with boost::span, and add the two boost headers to your project, or gsl::span and add gsl library to your codebase.

Thanks for the response, but your answer simply copy and pastes the example from the documentation and doesn't address the question. I'm asking about the function signature for vector-valued constraints, and the example that you copy-pasted from the docs only looks at a scalar-valued constraint function.

@Carl i didn't see that the question was specifically for vector-valued constraints (long day), i added a snippet for properly wrapping the function to use C++ objects
